# Infer the type of object keys

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

Is it possible in TypeScript to declare a structure so that the type of the `function` assigned to the `error` key in the `jQuery.ajax` would be inferred? We then could report on a type mismatch if one tries to assign a wrong function signature.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: listUrl,
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: OnSuccesCall,
    error: OnErrorCall
});

function OnErrorCall(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Aren't you using jquery.d.ts, if so it already defines it as `success? (data: any, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR): any;` and `error?(jqXHR: JQueryXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrown: string): any;` within `JQueryAjaxSettings`

Comment: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done for you already, to a limited extent (limited by [the definition you are using](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) and by the jQuery API which is full of optionality).

```
var listUrl = 'http://www.example.com/';
function OnSuccessCall (data, thing: boolean, another: boolean) {
    // implementation
}

function OnErrorCall () {
    // implementation
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: listUrl,
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: OnSuccessCall,
    error: OnErrorCall
});
```

In the above example, `OnSuccessCall` will cause TypeScript to issue a warning as it does not have a signature compatible with the success property, which expects `(data:any, textStatus: string, jqXhr: JQueryXHR) => any`.

Note that you could supply a function that omits any of these and it will be compatible (because you don't have to do anything with an argument you are passed).

Comment: Now I understand. Of course,  I only get an error when I introduce typings into the parameters as @Steve-Fenton showed. 

The error is not very helpful though:
`Error 2119 Argument of type '{ [x: number]: undefined; type: string; url: string; jsonp: string; dataType: string; success: (d...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. <path omitted>test.ts 142 16 test.ts
`
Ideally one should be able to fix the wrong signature easily. Any ideas?